# Instantiate animated objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jQuery mobile, I'm currently developing and app that needs to have several animations running independently, I found a really cool code for an animation that I need, it shows a pie timer countdown, the problem is with my lack of experience and knowledge of jQuery, I don't know how to instantiate new objects for this code.

Here is the code:

```
var methods = {
    init: function (options) {
        var state = {
            timer: null,
            timerSeconds: 60,
            callback: function () {},
            timerCurrent: 0,
            showPercentage: false,
            fill: false,
            color: '#CCC'
        };

        state = $.extend(state, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data(globalForPieTimer);
            if (!data) {
                $this.addClass(globalForPieTimer);
                $this.css({
                    fontSize: $this.width()
                });
                $this.data(globalForPieTimer, state);
                if (state.showPercentage) {
                    $this.find('.percent').show();
                }
                if (state.fill) {
                    $this.addClass('fill');
                }
                $this.pietimer('start');
            }
        });
    },

    stopWatch: function () {

        var data = $(this).data(globalForPieTimer);
        if (data) {
            var seconds = (data.timerFinish - (new Date().getTime())) / 1000;
            if (seconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(data.timer);
                $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 100);
                data.callback();
            } else {
                var percent = 100 - ((seconds / (data.timerSeconds)) * 100);
                $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', percent);
            }
        }
    },

    drawTimer: function (percent) {

        $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data(globalForPieTimer);
        if (data) {
            $this.html('<div class="percent"></div><div class="slice' + (percent > 50 ? ' gt50"' : '"') + '><div class="pie"></div>' + (percent > 50 ? '<div class="pie fill"></div>' : '') + '</div>');
            var deg = 360 / 100 * percent;
            $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
            });
            var secs = (data.timerSeconds) * ((100 - percent) / 100); /*NEW*/
            $this.find('.percent').html(Math.round(secs) + ''); /*Changed*/
            if (data.showPercentage) {
                $this.find('.percent').show();
            }
            if ($this.hasClass('fill')) {
                $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                    backgroundColor: data.color
                });
            } else {
                $this.find('.slice .pie').css({
                    borderColor: data.color
                });
            }
        }
    },

    start: function () {

        var data = $(this).data(globalForPieTimer);
        if (data) {
            data.timerFinish = new Date().getTime() + (data.timerSeconds * 1000);
            $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 0);
            data.timer = setInterval("$this.pietimer('stopWatch')", 50);
        }
    },

    reset: function () {
        console.log("flag 4");
        var data = $(this).data(globalForPieTimer);
        if (data) {
            clearInterval(data.timer);
            $(this).pietimer('drawTimer', 0);
        }
    }
};

$.fn.pietimer = function (method) {

    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pietimer');
    }
};



function runTimer(temp) {

    var auxx = "." + temp;
    console.log("click run timer class = " + auxx);
    $(auxx).pietimer({
        timerSeconds: 60,
        color: '#ccc',
        fill: '#ccc',
        showPercentage: true,
        callback: function () {
            console.log("flag 7");
            // alert("yahoo, timer is done!");
            $(auxx).pietimer('reset');
            $this.find('.percent').html(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:

When creating 2 timers if I click on one the other stops running, how do I instantiate the timers to work independently?

jsfiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/3nv6hm7k/)

Comment: by using: $(element).pietimer(); look into your function runTimer, there you'll find $(auxx).pietimer, like this you run an instance of pietimer.

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work for me, I can be doing it wrong though, can you give me an example. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am sorry - but what do you mean with "it didn't work for me", how should I know what you tried, what kind of error you got? Provide an example, show what you've done instead of copy code you don't understand.  See comment of user2570380 - runTimer is a wrapper, but all instances would have same params. in case you want different ones, use $(yourselectorforelement).pietimer({YOUR:OPTIONS});

Comment: I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nv6hm7k/ when you create 2 list items and you click on both timers one will stop, what I need is for them to work independently :)